# How can I test iPhone app performance and network usage without building/running from xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I want to check the memory and network usage of an iPhone app that I don't have the source code for.  How would I do this?

Comment: Please put your edit as an answer of your own question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally i could able to check the performance and real memory usage of the app. using the **Instruments.App** under **Xcode** installation directory/Applications/Instruments.app.

```
Connect your device to Mac.
    1.  Launch Instruments. The application automatically creates a new trace document and prompts you to select a template.
    2.  Select the Activity Monitor template under IOS section and and click the Choose button. Instruments adds the Activity Monitor instrument to the trace document.
    3.  In the Default Target menu of the trace document, choose Target and select the App you want to target.
    4.  Click on the Record button. Targeted App will be started running on your device.
    5.  Wait a few seconds so that Instruments can gather some data. Now perform you are operations on the App.
    6.  Click the Stop button after your actions completed.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Dear Ramakrishna it is not possible to check the performance of application with out the source code of the app .
If you have source than only you can check the performance of the app.By the help performance tool -> leak click you check the performance of the app.
Thank you I think this will help you dear